# CXF 3.0 with Spring and Apache 7 returns java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.cxf.wsdl.service.factory.ReflectionServiceFactoryBean

Tags: cxf

I am developing CXF Web Service using CXF 3.0 with Spring 2.4 and Apache 7.
The jaxws:endpoint statement in beans.xml as given below

< jaxws:endpoint id="orderProcess" implementor="com.webservices.impl.OrderProcessImpl" address="/OrderProcess"/>
returns the an error

Delegation Mode: PARENT_FIRST] failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.apache.cxf.wsdl.service.factory.ReflectionServiceFactoryBean
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:160)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1045)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:949)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:487)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:458)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:295)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:292)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:628)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:932)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:479)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:139)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:119)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:44)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:516)
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:148)
    ... 116 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.apache.cxf.wsdl.service.factory.ReflectionServiceFactoryBean
    at java.lang.J9VMInternals.verifyImpl(Native Method)
    at java.lang.J9VMInternals.verify(J9VMInternals.java:72)
    at java.lang.J9VMInternals.verify(J9VMInternals.java:70)
    at java.lang.J9VMInternals.prepare(J9VMInternals.java:433)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:537)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:156)
    ... 134 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.cxf.wsdl.service.factory.ReflectionServiceFactoryBean
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:423)
    at com.ibm.ws.bootstrap.ExtClassLoader.findClass(ExtClassLoader.java:191)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:660)
    at com.ibm.ws.bootstrap.ExtClassLoader.loadClass(ExtClassLoader.java:111)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:626)
    at com.ibm.ws.classloader.ProtectionClassLoader.loadClass(ProtectionClassLoader.java:62)
    at com.ibm.ws.classloader.ProtectionClassLoader.loadClass(ProtectionClassLoader.java:58)
    at com.ibm.ws.classloader.CompoundClassLoader.loadClass(CompoundClassLoader.java:511)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:626)
    at com.ibm.ws.classloader.CompoundClassLoader.loadClass(CompoundClassLoader.java:511)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:626)
    ... 140 more

I do not see a class org.apache.cxf.wsdl.service.factory.ReflectionServiceFactoryBean exists in any jar.  So, I am not sure why Web Sphere 7 is looking for this class.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to add the cxf-rt-wsdl-3.0.0.jar to your war.

Comment: Thanks.  That helped.  
Now I have a different error: 
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'orderProcess': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org/apache/ws/commons/schema/XmlSchemaCollection.read(Lorg/w3c/dom/Document;Ljava/lang/String;)Lorg/apache/ws/commons/schema/XmlSchema;

I have added init method to my service class even though it is not necessary.  Your reply is appreciated.

Comment: To be more descriptive, the error is:
NoSuchMethodError: org/apache/ws/commons/schema/XmlSchemaCollection.read(Lorg/w3c/dom/Document;Ljava/lang/String;)Lorg/apache/ws/commons/schema/XmlSchema;

I have used the latest xmlschema-core-2.1.0.jar file